# Force dismount iso from all network clients

Tags: batch-file, client, iso

I have an .iso image located in my hard drive. 10 PC clients in our network have access to this image and all of them have already mounted it with Windows Explorer (mount) process (Windows 10) or with WinCDemu (Windows 7). How can I dismount it by force, with a batch file?

I could, for example kill the process by

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (' net file ^|find /i "donatello.iso" ') do net file %%a /close
```

but I want also to dismount it from all of them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont think that's possible without tyerminal access to their machines

Comment: have a look at Powershell's `Dismount-DiskImage`.